# how to check form id with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form. And I want to check the form id.
Because I don't know the form id.

I try it like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkDuplicate",function(value) {
        var user_id = $(this).closest("form[id]").attr('id');
        console.log(user_id);
        var ka = $('#ID').val();
        if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(':checked') || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_3").is(':checked') || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_4").is(':checked')
 || $("#contactpersonen_canseestock_5").is(':checked')) && $('#idform :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
        console.log("checkbox checked; dont check duplicate email");
        return true;
        }
        else{
        console.log("checkbox not checked; check duplicate email");
         if ($("#contactpersonen_canseestock_2").is(":checked"))
        {
            console.log('hoi');
}
        console.log(ka);
        return false;
        }
    }, "Email adres bestaat al");

    jQuery.validator.classRuleSettings.checkTotal = { checkTotal: true };
```

Because #idform is not the form id.

But I get every time undefined. when I do this:

```
var user_id = $(this).closest("form[id]").attr('id');
```

This is the form:

http://webshop.verploegen.nl/klant-worden

But I cant see what the form id is

this is the selecter checkDuplicate:

```
 <div class="contact-label span2">
          <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
          <div class="contact-input-field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text span2 contactpersonen-email1 required checkDuplicate" id="contactpersonen_email1" name="contactpersonen_email1"></input>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does your `<form>` have an `id`?  Seems strange to call the variable `user_id` for a form.  `<form id='user_id'>` ??

Comment: please use instead 'var user_id = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');'

Comment: @RahulPatel can you explain?  If `.attr("id")` is going to work, then surely `$("form[id]")` will also work.

Comment: Likely an XY Problem, because why do you need to know the `id` of the `form`?  You can target it with `$("form")` or `$(this).closest("form")`, so there doesn't seem to be a need for the "id".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the jQuery.validator.addMethod() specification and i see that the function has three parameters:

- value = the current value of the validated element
- element = the element to be validated
- params = ...

If there is a element parameter it means that `this` is not directed at the element but to something else.

So if we do

```
$(element).closest("form[id]").attr('id')
```

i think it will work

Comment: Thank you. I triied that: var user_id = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
  console.log(user_id); but still undefined. I edit the post

Comment: Not sure why you think `form[id]` is an invalid selector, it's fine: https://jsfiddle.net/s1rhcgfm/

Comment: @SavantCode can you post the code where you use the validator "checkDuplicate"?

Comment: I did it like this: var hallo = $('form').attr('id'); and this works.

Comment: Oh very nice my account is blocked. How nice :)